# Are the poles of the $\frac{1}{e^{-s}-c}$ term simple?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I'd like to calculate the residues of a contour encircling
$$\frac{e^{st}}{s(e^{-s}-c)}$$ in terms of $s.$

There is one simple pole at $s = 0,$ but, if we set the other factor in the denominator $(e^{-s}-c)=0,$ we find there is a pole at $s = \log(1/c) + 2 \pi i n.$

Are the poles that occur at $s = \log(1/c) + 2 \pi i n$ simple?

If not, how could we calculate their residues? Wolfram seems to suggest the pole is simple but I don't know what "proves" this https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+x-%3Elog%281%2F2%29%2C+%28x-log%281%2F2%29%29%2F%28+e%5E%28+-x+%29-2+%29 .

Comment: Hint: the derivative of $e^{-s}-c$ is nonzero at $s=0$.

Comment: Don't I need the derivative of the whole $s(e^{-s}-c)$ term? If not, then I'm confused.

Comment: The factor $e^{st}/s$ approaches a nonzero finite value for roots of the other factor in the denominator, so you need only check such roots are simple poles of its reciprocal.

Comment: Okay, so you're treating $e^{st}/s$ as the numerator before applying L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: Well, you'd also need an $s-p$ factor, with $p=\ln c+2\pi in$.

Comment: Well, this approach assumes the poles are simple. I don't know that they are. How do you know?

Comment: Multiply your function by $s-s_n$ where $s_n$ iis one of the poles. The product has a limit when $s\to s_n.$ That means $s_n$ is a removable singularity of the product, i.e. the pole $s_n$ is simple. Moreover the limit is equal the residue of the original function at the pole $s_n.$

Comment: My approach isn't circular. If you compute the limit of $f(s)/g(s)$, where $f$ includes an $s-p$ factor and $g=e^{-s}-c$, the fact $g'(p)\ne0$ tells you L'Hôpital's rule gets a finite answer. And since the limit is finite, the pole is simple.

Comment: Okay, so if you only need to apply L'Hopital's rule once, then the pole is simple? That's an interesting way to view it, I'll have to keep that in mind.